# How to Use ProxyMatch or ProxyPassMatch with Regex for mapping multiple Context paths

Tags: regex, apache, contextpath

I am using **IBM's IHS Webserver** built on top of Apache Web server Version 2.2.4.

My requirement is to proxy pass a various Context path using regular expression in match.

I tried using `ProxyPassMatch` but I get below error

> ERROR: "Invalid ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch parameter.
>    Parameter must be in the form 'key=value'"

```
<LocationMatch "^/(ae/en|ar/en|ar/es|at/en|au/en|be/en|br/en)/">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
ProxyPass http://www.xyz.com.au:80/au/en/      #(should keep varying as per the regex matched in location match )
ProxyReverse http://www.xyz.com.au:80/au/en/   #(should keep varying as per the regex matched in location match )
</LocationMatch>
```

Kindly advice how this can be achieved.

Regards
Sridhar

Comment: This is unsolvable unless you provide exactly what you configured.

Answer (score 10):

If you put **ProxyPassMatch** iside a **LocationMatch** section, the first argument to ProxyPassMatch (regex) must be *omitted*. It will come from LocationMatch. Example from my ([working](http://gopal.lv)) configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName gopal.lv
ServerAlias gopal.lv www.gopal.lv
ProxyPreserveHost On

<LocationMatch "^/(img|js|css|att|thumb|banner)/(.+)$">
#Note: only 1 argument here
ProxyPassMatch "http://192.168.1.11/$1/$2"
</LocationMatch>

#Note we have 2 arguments here
ProxyPassMatch "^/(img|js|css|att|thumb|banner)/(.+)$" "http://192.168.1.11/$1/$2"
ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.12/

</VirtualHost>
```

Otherwise, you get the error

> ERROR: "Invalid ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch parameter. Parameter must be
>   in the form 'key=value'"

It is documented here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

Answer (score 2):

Always use separate lines for comments, and quote the string arguments.
There where bug regathering this thing in their bugzila, but I believe you are not using an old version.
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40439

```
<LocationMatch "^/(ae/en|ar/en|ar/es|at/en|au/en|be/en|br/en)/">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
#should keep varying as per the regex matched in location match
ProxyPass "http://www.xyz.com.au:80/au/en/"
#should keep varying as per the regex matched in location match
ProxyReverse "http://www.xyz.com.au:80/au/en/" 
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: add some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: "Invalid ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch parameter. Parameter must be in the form 'key=value'"

This may occur if you have e.g. used RewriteUrl-flags at the end of your Proxy-directive.